# P4 Copy Command

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce, I want to write batch script for copying same set files in one application to another application using p4 copy command. When I run in command prompt, commands are executed without any error. When executed through a trigger, it prompt trigger validation error? Kindly help.

Comment: You'll need to give us more details; please post the copy command you are running and the text of the trigger validation error.

Comment: The batch script is as below.                                                p4 -u admin -P 123456789 -p localhost:1666 -c localworkspace copy -n -v //depot/depot/Sample/BC/...#head //depot/depot/Sample/PC/...
p4 -u admin -P 123456789 -p localhost:1666 -c localworkspace submit -r -f submitunchanged -d "code check in"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute first rule of trigger writing is "assume **nothing** about the environment!"[1](http://www.robertcowham.com/blog/82/perforce-triggers-hintstipstrapspitfalls/).

Triggers are executed by the server process. Whilst a script may work locally during development/testing (via the command prompt) that is not guaranteed to be the case when the same commands are executed through a trigger.

Check your p4 environment on the server (using the [p4 set command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/set.html)) and compare that with your local environment.

The Perforce user manual has some [useful advice on writing triggers/daemons](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html) that I recommend reading.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for recommendations. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user1444645: If the advice helped then up-vote the answer / mark-as-answer.